# Get page to scroll continuously on its own on content added to div with ajax

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-masonry, vertical-scrolling

I have a somewhat obscure question that I'm not sure to which category is the solution.

The issue is on this site I made:

http://www.tumblrating.com/choose/mollysoda

Click'Reload' button at the bottom, When the page reloads, you will  see it automatically scrolls when the new pictures are added to the page. It does it for a finite amount of time, and then stops. I want to have it do that all the time! Help!

Bonus points: How can I have it do that all the time even if you just load the page normally rather than click the button?!

The photos are loaded to the Jquery masonry div with Jquery.Ajax, and then the div is reloaded with Masonry.Reload.

I'm not sure if the reason it scrolls has to do with Masonry, Jquery, or browser quirks- I'm looking at it in Firefox. How can I get this to work??? I will love you if you figure it out

Comment: This website makes my browser memory management sense want to cry